# Rails 3 Ajax success message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a voting system that i'm trying to Ajax.

In the view i have:

```
<div id="yes"><%=button_to 'Vote',vote_path(c),:id=>c.id,:remote=>true,:html=>{:class=>"vote"}%></div>

and the controller goes:
```

`def vote

```
    number=Video.find(params[:id])
    number.increment!(:votes)
    if number.update_attributes(params[:votes])
       flash[:notice] = "Vote Recorded Successfully."

    render :text => number.votes  

   end`
```

When a user votes, i want to hide the vote button and display a message like "Thanks for Voting".

So, in my application.js, i have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".vote").bind("ajax:success",function(evt,xhr,settings){
       var $ent=$(this);
        $ent.find(("div.yes")).hide(100);
    }
    }
);
```

Please point me to some resource to accomplish this.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return something jQuery can handle, plain JSON works fine:

```
def vote
  ...
  render :json => {:votes => number.votes}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rendering :text, render a erb.js view. This is called unobtrusive javascript.

[See here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript)